# Interface with unknown properties

Tags: go

I'm trying to use the [`Unmarshal` method](https://godoc.org/github.com/ericaro/frontmatter#Unmarshal) from the [frontmatter](https://godoc.org/github.com/ericaro/frontmatter) package to parse front matter from a markdown file.

The type signature for the function is as follows

```
func Unmarshal(data []byte, v interface{}) (err error)
```

I've got the byte data and I understand that I need to pass an interface/struct with the appropriate fields as the second argument—however I don't know what the fields are going to be in the files that I parse and it's important that I don't lose data.

Internally this package uses [yaml.v2](https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml) which provides a more comprehensive example for defining the interface before unmarshaling.

```
type T struct {
    A string
    B struct {
        RenamedC int   `yaml:"c"`
        D        []int `yaml:",flow"`
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of the struct `t` and pass a pointer to `t` through to `Unmarshal`.

```
t := T{}

err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &t)
```

As I understand, this is only going to work if the YAML looks like this:

```
a: Easy!
b:
  c: 2
  d: [3, 4]
```

The second example looks closer to what I need. Rather than creating a struct, it seems to use a map of `interface{} -> interface{}`.

```
m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})

err = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &m)
```

I'm relatively new to Go and to me this looks like a generic map, which would be ideal for reading in unknown values.

I've adapted the example for my own project and ended up with the following code.

```
m := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
err := frontmatter.Unmarshal(data, &m)
```

But this results in a runtime error

> ```
> panic: reflect: NumField of non-struct type
> ```

Full stacktrace [here](https://gist.github.com/danprince/b5672db782a4f14451e2).

---

Am I heading in the right direction? If so, what's going wrong?

Comment: I can't really help you as I haven't played with these packages, but at a quick glance frontmatter.Unmarshal doesn't seem to do any checks whether the second argument is a struct or not, yet it calls reflect.NumField on it which will panic on non-structs. I'm guessing you'll have to find another way if you want to unmarshal into a map.

Comment: `frontmatter` assumes you're going to pass in a pointer to a struct but doesn't actually check for this to be the case. I'd advice for a better, more robust an generalized implementation if there's one available.

Comment: But `frontmatter` doesn't actually do anything with the pointer itself, it just [forwards it on to `yaml.Unmarshal`](https://github.com/ericaro/frontmatter/blob/master/frontmatter.go#L73) which is shown to take a map in the example.

Comment: @DanPrince correct, but after doing that it then calls `frontmatter.WriteString`, which calls `findField` which calls reflect's `NumField`, blindly assuming that you're passing a pointer to a struct.

Comment: Ah, yep. Should have seen that from the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the raw `yaml.Unmarshal` method is robust enough to only pick up the front matter, even when presented with the entire file.

The solution I ended up using looks like this.

```
// read file made up of front matter and content
data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)

if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
}

meta := make(map[interface{}]interface{})
yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &meta)
```

This means dropping the `frontmatter` package and using the `yaml` package directly.